# Callback in Firestore still returning null values from database

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After my last question regarding reading data from a Firestore collection, I had to create a callback function in order to use the asynchronized data that Firestore sends. However, even with the callback function created, security rules in Firestore console overruled and a guarantee that there is a connection between my app and the database, I still get a null value.

Here is my callback interface

```
public interface Callback {

    void myResponseCallback(String result);

}
```

And here is my updated code to work with this callback:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

DocumentReference docRef =
        db.collection("usuarios")
                .document("idtest");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    tvMenu = findViewById(R.id.tvMainMenu);
    btOpenOs = findViewById(R.id.btNewOs);

}


public void readDataFromFirestore(Callback callback){
    //The app doesn't even enter this part of the code, as if they stop right at the first IF
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    dbValue = document.getString("palavra");
                    //tvMenu.setText(dbValue); DOESN'T WORK
                    Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "String Value: " + document.getString("palavra"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            callback.myResponseCallback(dbValue);
        }
    });
}

public void setDataFromFirestore() {
    readDataFromFirestore(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void myResponseCallback(String result) {
            tvMenu.setText(result);
             //Returns null
            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "Result: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}


public void openOsActivity(View view) {
   /* Intent osIntent = new Intent(this, OsActivity.class);
    startActivity(osIntent);*/

    setDataFromFirestore();
}
```

The Toast from setDataFromFirestore() returns a "Result: null". Here's a picture of my FireStore collection of which I'm trying to read the field "palavra":

[image: FireStore Collection]

What exactly am I doing wrong here? It's my first time with Firestore and even after reading the documentation and other SO posts, I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Running the debugger, it seems that the result is also null. Here is a image from it:

[image: Debugger Info]

However I could use some help understanding some of the information in there.

Comment: It sounds like either `if (task.isSuccessful()) {` or `if (document.exists()) {` is not passing then. I recommend setting a breakpoint on that first one, running in the debugger and checking if you get a result/value.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did add a picture of the results that the debugger gave me, and dbValue does seem to be null. However, I could be missing some vital info in there since I do not have much experience with it. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code loads `.document("idtest")`, but the screenshot has a document named `idteste` with an extra `e` at the end.

Comment: Oh, that was absolutely my lack of attention fault, it worked after changing it to "idteste". Sorry about this one, I guess I just needed a fresh pair of eyes. Thank you so much!

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @Leonardo. And no worries about posting, we all have occasional blind spots and those are a lot easier for folks who don't know your project, docs and code at all. :)

I voted to close the question as a typo btw, since it's unlikely that folks who find themselves in the same situation in the future will find this post and benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as Frank van Puffelen described was that  my code was loading "idtest" instead of idteste, as it is in my firestore database. Apart from that, it seems that the callback function made all of this possible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).